# How can I show the child div inside the parent div using javascript without triggering the others

Tags: javascript, html

*͏͏ ͏Sorry for huge title͏͏͏ *͏

I have an issue today that I want to discuss with you guys.
I have this problem that, when I click a ***button "COMMENT"***, it triggers JavaScript code to display a ***CHILD.div*** inside the ***PARENT.div***, but instead it triggers the one in the upper!

**Code snippet:**

```js
function toggleHiddenDiv(id) {
  var div = document.getElementById(id);
  div.style.display = div.style.display == "block" ? "none" : "block";
}

function toggleVisibleDiv(id) {
  var div = document.getElementById(id);
  div.style.display = div.style.display == "none" ? "block" : "none";
}
```

```html
<div class="posted_post_window">
  <span class="pfpicture"><img src="img/nurkiprofil.jpg" /><span class="pfname">Nurudin Imsirovic</span></span><span class="close" onclick="this.parentNode.parentNode.removeChild(this.parentNode);"></span>
  <div class="content">Ali je ovo smor ljudi moji...</div>
  <div class="react_ui"><button>LIKE</button><button>SHARE</button><button onclick="toggleHiddenDiv('submitcontainer');">COMMENT</button><button>REPORT</button></div>
  <div class="comments_ui">
    <div class="caption">Comments</div>
    <div class="container"><br>
      <div class="pfcontainer"><img src="img/aldinprofil.jpg" alt="Profile Picture" /><span class="pfname">Aldin Hadžić</span></div>
      <span class="comment">Poz</span>
    </div>

    <div class="container"><br>
      <div class="pfcontainer"><img src="img/osmanprofil.jpg" alt="Profile Picture" /><span class="pfname">Osman Hasić</span></div>
      <span class="comment">Test123Test123Test123Test123Test123Test123Test123Test123Test123Tes
        t123Test123Test123Test123Test123Test123Test123Test123Test123Test1
        23Test123Test123Test123Test123Test123Test123Test123Test123Test123Test12
        3Test123Test123Test123Test123Test123Test123Test123Test123Test123Test123Tes
        t123Test123Test123Test123Test123Test123Test123Test123Test123Test123Test123Test
        123Test123Test123Test123Test123Test123Test123Test123Test123Test123</span>
    </div>

    <div class="container"><br>
      <div class="pfcontainer"><img src="img/eldanprofil.jpg" alt="Profile Picture" /><span class="pfname">Eldan Delić</span></div>
      <span class="comment">xDDDDDD</span>
    </div>

    <div id="submitcontainer" class="submitcontainer">
      <div class="pfcontainer">
        <img src="img/nurkiprofil.jpg" /><span class="pfname">Nurudin Imsirovic</span>
        <textarea name="s.comment" rows="4"></textarea>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

So the issue for me is the

```
<button onclick="toggleHiddenDiv('submitcontainer');">COMMENT</button>
```

How can I make JavaScript only take ID's from the called PARENT.div?

As always, thanks in advance!

Comment: I removed your email addresses, because the idea of this site is that everybody learns from the discussion that your question might create. People will contact you through the comments if they have anything to ask or say, no need for email.

Comment: They way you write your `toggleHiddenDiv(id)` and `toggleVisibleDiv(id)`, they do exactly the same thing, you only need one.

Comment: I don't fully understand your problem, what is it exactly that you want and what is it that is happening now. Please name the element that you want to hide by `id` or `class`, and also the one that is being hidden now, so we know what to do.

Comment: Your comment button is hiding or showing the element by its id attribute.  There's no reason for that action to be relative to each comment button.  Also, this gives me the strong impression that your ids are not unique, which is also a problem.  There should only ever be one element with the id of "submitcontainer".  For others that are confused, OP tried to provide a video in the question.  It was removed, but I feel it does help clarify what's going on, so I've reuploaded it to imgur: http://i.imgur.com/fQHICT0.gif

Comment: I think the key missing information is that there are more than one `.posted_post_window` elements in OPs actual code, which is why the problem is happening.  Each `.posted_post_window` presumably has a `#submitcontainer` element.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is that you're trying to target the element by its id attribute, but you have multiple elements with the same id in the document.  This is illegal in HTML and you should remove those ids or make them unique.  You are also using `onclick` attributes in your HTML this is highly inadvisable.  you should be using [event listeners](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener) instead, but that aside, your button clicks have no way of knowing which container was clicked or needs targeted.  As it stands, you could pass a context reference to the methods and use that to tell which one should be show or hidden.  Not that I've also changed the syntax for your show/hide methods.  Going forward, to target an id you would use `toggleHiddenDiv('#mydiv')`.

```js
function toggleHiddenDiv(selector, context) {
  context = context ? context : document.body;
  var div = context.querySelector(selector);
  div.style.display = div.style.display == "block" ? "none" : "block";
}

function toggleVisibleDiv(selector, context) {
  context = context ? context : document.body;
  var div = context.querySelector(selector);
  div.style.display = div.style.display == "none" ? "block" : "none";
}
```

```html
<div class="posted_post_window">
  <span class="pfpicture"><img src="img/nurkiprofil.jpg" /><span class="pfname">Nurudin Imsirovic</span></span><span class="close" onclick="this.parentNode.parentNode.removeChild(this.parentNode);"></span>
  <div class="content">Ali je ovo smor ljudi moji...</div>
  <div class="react_ui"><button>LIKE</button><button>SHARE</button><button onclick="toggleHiddenDiv('.submitcontainer', this.parentNode.parentNode);">COMMENT</button><button>REPORT</button></div>
  <div class="comments_ui">
    <div class="caption">Comments</div>
    <div class="container"><br>
      <div class="pfcontainer"><img src="img/aldinprofil.jpg" alt="Profile Picture" /><span class="pfname">Aldin Hadžić</span></div>
      <span class="comment">Poz</span>
    </div>

    <div class="container"><br>
      <div class="pfcontainer"><img src="img/osmanprofil.jpg" alt="Profile Picture" /><span class="pfname">Osman Hasić</span></div>
      <span class="comment">Test123Test123Test123Test123Test123Test123Test123Test123Test123Tes
        t123Test123Test123Test123Test123Test123Test123Test123Test123Test1
        23Test123Test123Test123Test123Test123Test123Test123Test123Test123Test12
        3Test123Test123Test123Test123Test123Test123Test123Test123Test123Test123Tes
        t123Test123Test123Test123Test123Test123Test123Test123Test123Test123Test123Test
        123Test123Test123Test123Test123Test123Test123Test123Test123Test123</span>
    </div>

    <div class="container"><br>
      <div class="pfcontainer"><img src="img/eldanprofil.jpg" alt="Profile Picture" /><span class="pfname">Eldan Delić</span></div>
      <span class="comment">xDDDDDD</span>
    </div>

    <div class="submitcontainer" style="display:none">
      <div class="pfcontainer">
        <img src="img/nurkiprofil.jpg" /><span class="pfname">Nurudin Imsirovic</span>
        <textarea name="s.comment" rows="4"></textarea>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you so much sir :D
This works absolutely the way I wanted!

Comment: @SoricyInfinitive You're welcome.  Glad I could help.